# EditText to String Returning no Value

Tags: android, android-layout

I've tried converting an EditText value to string repeatedly, and have tried everything I can find, but I am unable to correctly get the string value from an EditText value, then display it in a dialog. I made a basic activity to test it. Where am I going wrong? All this program is is one edittext box and one button.

```
package com.bensherman.example.etts;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditTextToStringActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eTb);
        String convtext = text.getText().toString();


        final Builder vars = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        vars.setTitle("Saved Information");
        vars.setMessage("Entered Text: " + convtext);

        Button savedvars = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showButton);
        savedvars.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vars.show();
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eTb"
        android:hint = "Enter Text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/showButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does the EditText field have default text? You are loading its value at creation time, but where is the value set?

Comment: Did you give the EditText a text value with `android:text=""` in your xml file?

Comment: What text is actually _in_ the EditText during onCreate?  I'm guessing its empty to start (I don't see you setting anything in it programmatically) and typically an EditText is empty when an Activity is being created.

Comment: The editText has a hint, but nothing else. I'll post the XML

Comment: The hint can't be retrieved using getText...

Comment: I understand what you mean now. Also, is it possible to display a string in textview that's taken from an activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write this 2 line into the onClick() method

```
String convtext = text.getText().toString();
vars.setMessage("Entered Text: " + convtext);
```

or you can also write like this way

```
vars.setMessage("Entered Text: " + text.getText().toString());
```

and than

```
vars.show();
```

Comment: What if I just wanted to save the editText and then display it it another activity? I know how to use saved preferences, etc, but do I need something like a save button?

Comment: if you save the value of edittext like in oncreate time and then i have write some into the edittext and then click on button. now what happen i got the saved value or changed value?

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the text as soon as you declare/initialize your EditText which is probably at the time empty.

You need to get the text when the button is clicked - at which time, I presume, will be filled with some text by the user.

So do this:

```
final EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eTb);
final Builder vars = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

Button savedvars = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showButton);
    savedvars.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String convtext = text.getText().toString();
            vars.setTitle("Saved Information");
            vars.setMessage("Entered Text: " + convtext);
            vars.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks! If I didn't have a button to show the string, how would the code be different?

Comment: Not so much different bensherms; you just have to get the text after the fact that a user has typed something in your EditBox and not just right after you declared it.  In your case you're marking this with a button click.  If you have a use case of your activity, and if you share the logic, I'll be happy to further explain where to ask for the Text better. I hope this helps, best, -serkan

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem of when your code gets executed. You are setting the `convtext` variable to the contents of the editText at activity creation time (in onCreate). At this point, the editText is always empty.

When the user clicks the button, then you're showing the dialog box using the vars that contain convtext (which is still empty).  What you have to do is get the text from the editText inside the onClickListener: